# HTTP error 307 while trying Powershell remoting

Tags: powershell, remote-access, remote-desktop

My goal is to run commands from one VM to another from Powershell - nothing complicated, right?

Both VMs are in same subnet, they can Ping each other. If I open mstsc, I can connect with no problems. So far, so good.

Here is my code (works in other environments like a charm):

```
$PSWD = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username, $PSWD )
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName PC000003 -Credential $cred
```

And here is what I get -

```
New-Pssession : [PC00003] Connecting to remote server PC000003 failed 
with the following error message : The WinRM client received an HTTP 
status code of 307 from the remote WS-Management service. For more info...
```

I've tried authentication switches, no changes. Also tried same between two VMs and between host and VM, same results. Switching between name and IP - same results.

Username and password is correct and has necessary rights (since I can connect via mstsc successfully).
Google returns very few mentions of Status code 307, and most of them are about Exchange + Office 365 errors.

Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using TEST-WSMAN. This command let should tell if remoting has been enabled within each VM. If that is the case or your not suer you can run Set-WSManQuickConfig. That should enalbe remoting. There are several help files with Powershell Help about_Remote & about_Remote_TroubleShooting.

Comment: Hello, I had launched `Enable-PSRemoting` on both VMs before. I executed `Set-WSManQuickConfig` on both VMs, no changes there. Also about_Remote_Troubleshooting doesn't contain anything related to this HTTP 307 error.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over same error. All other things woked, ping, terminal connection, network shares etc. But found out that our firewall blocked Powershell connections. Added rule to let Powershell connections through and problem solved.